# How to use binary search on an existing SortedList with a key function?

Tags: python, binary-search, sortedcontainers

I would like to use binary search on a [`SortedList`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedlist) with a key function, e.g. similarly to [`bisect_right()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module. However, [`SortedList.bisect_right()`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList.bisect_right) only supports searching by value. How to make it work with a key function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `SortedList` already and it's sorted by the given key, you can use [`bisect.bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) on that, e.g.:

```
bisect.bisect_right(sorted_list, value, key=keyfunc)
```

If you need to search repeatedly, it would be more efficient to create a [`SortedKeyList`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedkeylist) and use its [`bisect_key_right()`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList.bisect_key_right) method. The extra efficiency comes from not indexing the sorted list during a binary search, as that itself is a `O(log(n))` [operation](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList.__getitem__).

Comment: This is technically a call you can perform, but it relies on the SortedList already being sorted by the given key. If it is, then you could have just used the SortedList's `bisect_right` method, and if it's not, then this will give incorrect results.

Comment: @user2357112 Imagine the SortedList has entries sorted by date. But now you want to bisect by *year*. That **is** compatible. And `bisect.bisect_right` gets the job done while the list's method doesn't (unless you create some fake object with the first or last date of the desired year).

Comment: Note that `bisect_key_right` is for if you have a key value *without* a corresponding element - for example, if you've got strings sorted by length, `bisect_key_right` would take a length rather than a string. If you want to provide an element, that's just `bisect_right`, not `bisect_key_right`.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the `key` for a `SortedList` in its constructor.

https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedList

The `SortedList` is sorted according to that key, and the `bisect` methods in `SortedList` necessarily use the same key, since bisection requires an understanding of how the list is sorted.

Comment: You should make clear that you're referring to the bisect member functions and *not* the functions in the `bisect` module.